# Parsing TCP Packets back together

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I am working on a tool that takes a pcap file (from wireshark in this case), and attempts to parse out data from the TCP packets.

Now in this case, I only care about the data in one direction. So my logic was to sort out each wireshark captured packet into a list by the protocol-destIP-sourceIP-destPort-sorcePort.

So from this point, I now have a list of only packets for one direction on a particular port.

From there I just want to be able to walk through the bodies of the TCP payloads in order. is it as simple as then going in order by Sequence numbers?

I would simply take the first sequence number captured, add the payload size to it and expect that to be the next TCP packet sent? Is there more to this that I am missing?

I was noticing when sorting the interfaces this way, eventually I would come up to a sequence that dosent make sense. I guess I could just assume that is the start of the next stream? I know it becomes more difficult if I have to consider traffic going back and forth... but in this case I only want to watch packets in one direction.

Comment: The sequence number is the number of the first data byte in the TCP segment, but remember that the initial sequence number is a random number, and the sequence numbers can wrap back to `0`.

Comment: is there a standard for when it wraps back to zero? I don't think that is the case here.. it almost seems like in some of the data I am seeing a new stream on the same tuple start

Comment: The TCP standard is _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_. You should be familiar with it if you are attempting to (basically) recreate what TCP is doing.

Comment: One of the things I have been seeing is the sequence number be different as I trace down... like I will follow a bunch of sequence numbers that make sense and then suddenly have a different one on the same tuple. I can't tell if it is just a new stream opening, it isn't wrapping because the number isn't 0

Comment: What others are telling you here is that you need to read the documentation (RFC). Asking more questions is ignoring their advice.

Comment: It isn't that simple. There are complete and partial retransmissions to think about, and out of sequence segments. Wireshark already supports a 'follow' operation, which stitches the data of a TCP session back together. Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark captures the packet on the wire. It might happen that the packets don't arrive in sequential order, that packets are corrupt (bad checksum), that there are duplicate packets ... - and this is ignoring possible attacks designed to confuse the analysis. The TCP stack will take care of all these problems so that the application gets the right packets, but Wireshark works outside the TCP stack. Thus, while in most cases your simple procedure will likely work (assuming that you at least check TCP flags for start and end of connection), it might fail in some cases.

Comment: Do you have any idea what cases it would fail? It seems that it works for 90% from my testing, but I am trying to figure out where I go wrong

Comment: @JDOe: I've included several cases in my answer. I have no idea in which cases it fails in your specific case since I don't have access to your data and your code.

Comment: Very true.  FOr a while the sequence number makes sense, but then in the data the sequence number drops, I think thats the main issue I am chasing right now.. understanding if I am just looking at a new stream or something else.

Comment: @JDOe: I've somehow assumed that you will at least check the TCP flags to find out where a connection starts end ends (i.e. SYN and FIN). Looks like I was wrong with this assumption. If you don't you will not detect if the same ports are reused in a later connection.